# How to generate documentation from css file?

Tags: php, css, docbook, phpdoc

I reference to [CSSDoc](http://cssdoc.net/) specification and want to generate comment  documentation from css file. The first thought used phpdocumentor tool. When execute `phpdoc -o HTML:frames:default -f main.css -t docs` command, i got ***"File not parsed,not a php file"*** error message. Please tell me how to generate documentation from css file by auto-documentation tools. Should be used Doxygen,JavaDoc tool or write a new parser with existing tools. Thanks~~~~

Comment: i find http://github.com/imedo/css_doc tool. Have other tools in php?